# When to use "a"

Tags: gramática

"Last week I saw my husband's aunt" translated to "La semana pasada vi *a* la tia de mi esposo". I always miss the little "a" when I see a sentence like this. Could someone help me summarize when it is needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spanish when the direct object is a person and is not given by pronoun it always bare the article *«a»*.  Always.

> *La semana pasada vi **a** la tía de mi esposo.*
>   *La semana pasada la vi.*

If you repeat the pronoun for emphasis, then you also add *«a»*.

> *La semana pasada la vi **a** ella.*

Sometimes it is also required when the object is animate, particularly if it is determinate.

> *Mi gato cazó **al** ratón.*
>   *Mi gato cazó un ratón.*

The direct object will never use preposition *«a»* for innanimated objects.

> *La semana pasada vi la casa de mis sueños.*
>   *La semana pasada la vi.*

The indirect object will always use the preposition *«a»* or the dative form of the pronoun, regardless if it is personal, animate, innanimate, determinate or indeterminate.

> *Puse una estrella **a** mi árbol de navidad.*
>   *Le puse una estrella.*

You can combine the dative pronoun with the explicit indirect object for emphasis.

> *Le puse una estrella **a** mi árbol de navidad.*

In these example, if you prefere to use a pronoun for the direct object, it will use the accusative pronoun:

> *Puse la estrella a mi árbol de navidad.*
>   *La puse a mi árbol de navidad.*

However if there are two third-person pronouns, the indirect object (dative) pronoun will be changed for the reflexive third-person pronoun.

> *Se la puse.*

But back to the topic of the preposition *«a»*.  If a verb has both direct and indirect object and the direct object is a person, both objects will have the preposition:

> *El padre entregó **a** su hija **al** novio.*

or

> *El padre entregó **al** novio **a** su hija.*

Some times it might become a little ambiguous, as you can see; just in this case the rule of the personal direct object always having the preposition might be dropped:

> *El padre entregó su hija **al** novio.*
>   *El padre entregó **al** novio su hija.*

However, when using a personal name as direct object, the preposition *«a»* cannot be dropped:

> *El padre entregó **a** Sandra **al** novio.*
>   *El padre entregó **al** novio **a** Sandra.*

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Do I still use personal a in "sabré quién soy." Putting the "a" before quién?

Comment: It would be incorrect. _«quién soy»_ is a phrase, not a person. In the sentence _«Sabré quien soy»_ _(“**I** will know who I am”)_, the object is what answers the question _«¿Qué sabré?»_ _(“What will **I** know?”)_, and the answer _«quien soy»_ _(“who I am”)_ is not a person.